# Why are Landsat-8 derived NDVI values higher than SAVI values?

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi, landsat-8, vegetation-index, savi

I have calculated NDVI and SAVI vegetation indices for a landsat-8 image. I am unexpectedly getting higher values for the NDVI than SAVI. What may be causing these unusual results?

```
NDVI=0.46
SAVI=0.34
```

Specific band pixel values are:

```
toa b4- 0.130
toa b5- 0.365
L= 0.5 taken
```

Comment: What are you trying to infer? These are similar but different indices that are not dependent on one another. There can be lower or higher values for one index over the other. It is meaningless unless given the context. Please edit your question to include any additional information you have.

Comment: Please provide more details or examples explaining why you believe the NDVI values should be lower than SAVI.